# Display data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This code allows me to display panda dataframe contents in Jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
# create a simple dataset of people
data = {'Name': ["John", "Anna", "Peter", "Linda"],
'Location' : ["New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "London"],
'Age' : [24, 13, 53, 33]
}
data_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)
# IPython.display allows "pretty printing" of dataframes
# in the Jupyter notebook
display(data_pandas)
```

However, I am not using Jupyter notebook. I am using pycharm and Anaconda (python v3.6). How should I display `data_pandas` if I am not using Jupyter?

Comment: Maybe you can use print(data_pandas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put `data_pandas` in a cell and run that cell. It will display the content in output.

[image]

To be able to do the same thing in pycharm you will have to run anaconda notebook from pycharm. Which works like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html

Then it's basically same as running a normal jupyter notebook on a different browser.

If you are running a normal python program and want an inline output, it's not going to happen. You will have to at least run an Ipython program to do so. Iteractive python.

Comment: Do I need to be using Jupyter to put `data_pandas` in a cell? I am using pycharm, not Jupyter.

Comment: oh 2 mins. checking.

Comment: @user3848207 You can run a jupyter notebook in pycharm as well, if you like. Btw, if you are doing analysis, notebook will be better than a dev environment. But with print(data_pandas), you should be able to see it in the console when you run the python file.