# The Jupyter do not show border lines and grey blocks

Tags: pandas, numpy

everybody. I learn NumPy and pandas with the Jupyter. When printing, it does not show borderlines and grey blocks. Example:

[image: actual_result]

Should be:

[image: expected]

How to solve it? Thank you very much, everybody.

Comment: Try just using `b` instead of `print(b)` as your last line.

Comment: I have tried it. Succes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The 'borderlines and grey blocks' view is a rendered HTML version of your dataframe.

You can either just use `b` as @Carlos Bergillos mentioned, or use

```py
from IPython.display import display

display(b)
```

Please see other very similar questions:

- [Show DataFrame as table in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook)
- [Display DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook, Depending on a Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564440/display-dataframe-in-jupyter-notebook-depending-on-a-condition)
- [Display data in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591589/display-data-in-pandas-dataframe)